# Manipulating colors in svg

Tags: css, svg, html5-canvas, sublimetext3

I have got multiple inline svg files. These svg's are multi colored svg files. Is there a way to convert all colors in the inline svg file to be `#FFFFFF`? (I use sublime 3)

Note: I'm looking for a way to update the colors inside the inline svg itself.

EDIT:

example:

```
<svg><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FF6600" d="M306.5 64.2v-0.1l0.3-0.4 9.2-22.1 -106.3-2.4 ....."/><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#BCBEC0" d="M414 83.6l0.5 ...."/><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#E5E5E5" d="M430.5 319.2l-0.1 1.2 -7.2 3.9 ..."/><linearGradient id="SVG1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="264.3843" y1="81.6587" x2="272.8713" y2="413.0609"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#171312"/><stop offset="0.4471" style="stop-color:#171312;stop-opacity:0"/><stop offset="0.8549" class="b_vg" stop-color="#171312"/></linearGradient></svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. See my edit.

Comment: Is this a programming question i.e. do you want some javascript that can change the paths or is this a can I do this in the sublimetext3 editor. The latter being non-programming would be off-topic.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Thanks. If you can give me a JS or similar that can rename all hex colors to `#FFFFFF`, that's all what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName("path") will get a collection of paths (assuming that's where all the colours are set). Then just iterate over those calling setAttribute.

```
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path"); 
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) { 
    paths[i].setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can this be added in the svg file with script tags?

Comment: Sure, that's exactly where it's supposed to go.